# database query and fetch_array to assign global session

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$query=sprintf("SELECT * FROM membertable WHERE (name='%s' AND pass='%s') AND activation='%s';",
                       $username,$password,"NULL");

$query=$this->db->query($query);
$result=$query->result_array();
```

I would like to assign that result to _SESSION but

```
session_start();
$_SESSION=$result;
```

results in an incorrect result, someone could help me with this little problem ?

Comment: $result is an array so try to say it in another array of session variable.

Comment: what does it mean "incorrect result"? what does return $result itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `application/config/autoload.php`, and in the `$autoload['libraries']` array, add 'session':

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(
    'session'
     // you may have some other libraries in here too
);
```

Now, to store the result, use

```
$this->session->set_userdata('db_result', $result);
```

And to retrieve it

```
$this->session->userdata('db_result');
```

Comment: Does that mean that I wwon't have to use session-start in every page any more ?

Comment: Yes, CodeIgniter makes life easier for you in many ways, you just have to let it help out.

Comment: Thanks joe, but what is the equivalent of $_SESSION['username'] in which username is a database column name ?

Comment: Also, when I direct log in user to another page how can I retain his state in session ? In native php session, I just issue "session_start(), then choose the column name to put in $_SESSION[columnNAME]", it automatically works then.

Comment: You'd need to do: `foreach ($result AS $k => $v) { $this->session->set_userdata($k, $v); }`, then you can just do `$this->session->userdata('username')` to get the username